# m2doc ERROR: EClassifier=String is not registered in the current environment

Tags: papyrus, m2doc

I use m2doc in eclipse papyrus. When I click on the element, I can see its properties.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYTQ2.png)

It has the property "Name".

But when I use `self.name` in m2doc interpreter, I got this error: `m2doc ERROR: EClassifier=String is not registered in the current environment (117, 122)`

If I use `self.visibility` or `self.namespace`, I can get the correct value in the properties view.

Here, `self` is the variable I defined when I create my m2doc project, and its value is the element I clicked on.

I went through some other questions on stack overflow, one of a related question is this: [EClassifier=Boolean is not registered in the current environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58845188/eclassifier-boolean-is-not-registered-in-the-current-environment)

But the answer did not help me, because the properties of the element `self` are all default properties of a papyrus model element, I did not create them, and I cannot define their types. I just filled in the blanks when I created the element.

I want to get the name of the element, how can I achieve that? Please help me, thank you.

Comment: I used self.eGet('name'), it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Papyrus metamodel, it looks like EAttribute "name" is of type `org.eclipse.uml2.types/model/Types.ecore#//String`.
Did you register the nsURI of Types.ecore?

Comment: I add [http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/5.0.0/Types] and now it works. Thank you very much.